# Complements: -ing form or infinitives

Tags: verbs, gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund, complements

Not sure if this was already discussed, but I am confused about the use of -ing form/infinitives as complements. I've found in several threads in Stack Exchange that the verb "to be" has to be followed with an infinitive form like in the example:

> What we want is to be free.

or

> All you can do is (to) wait for the results.

However, I've found on other resource that verbs in their -ing form are used as complements too, like in [this sentence](https://www.dictionary.com/e/whats-a-gerund/?prev=t):

> The group’s main goal is eliminating poverty.

Even Practical English Usage by Michael Swan states that -ing forms can be used as complements (like: "My favorite activity is reading poetry").

Then I am wondering if the below sentences can be considered correct:

> What we want is being free.
>
> All you can do is waiting for the results.

If the above examples are ungrammatical, may I know the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All you can do is WAIT. <sup>OK</sup>
>
> All you can do is WAITING. <sup>unidiomatic</sup>
>
> What we want is TO BE free. <sup>OK</sup>
>
> What we want is BEING free.  <sup>unidiomatic</sup>

The reason the **ing**-forms do not work here, I believe, is that this syntactic pattern is elliptical, and the **ing**-form of the verb is not a valid complement for the verbs  WANT and CAN.

All you can do is, [you can] wait.

All you can do is, [you can] waiting.  <sup>no</sup>

What we want is, [we want] to be free.

What we want is, [we want] being free. <sup>no</sup>

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answer. Then, I guess we are in a sort of blurred area when it comes to the verb "to be" + ing form or infinitives. Based on your answer, I could simply rephrase the sentences this way: "Your only option is waiting (for the results)" and "Our strongest desire is being free". I don't know if those'd sound odd to a native speaker's ear, but I'm pretty sure they are not ungrammatical. Bottom line: it is the context (like the use of the verbs "can" or "want") that somehow decides what should follow the verb "to be' (either an infinitive or -ing form). Do you agree?

Comment: Yes. Those are grammatical. But I wouldn't call it a "gray area" relating to the verb-to-be.  The syntax of the examples in your question and the syntax of these sentences in your comment is quite different.  In the OP the subject of **is** is a clause (**all you can do** and **what we want**) whereas in the sentences in your comment, the subject of **is** is a simple noun phrase.